nextjs nested api routes not found
I have a nextjs app with the tree below. I have api routes in the api directory. Some of the routes return a 404. Specifically /api/auth/login and /api/auth/register.
The /api and /api/auth routes file work correctly. Also, I have tested both get and post routes.
.
├── app
│   ├── api
│   │   ├── auth
│   │   │   ├── login
│   │   │   │   └── route.ts
│   │   │   ├── register
│   │   │   │   └── route.ts
│   │   │   └── route.ts
│   │   ├── registry-accounts
│   │   │   └── route.ts
│   │   └── route.ts
│   ├── auth
│   │   ├── layout.tsx
│   │   ├── login
│   │   │   └── page.tsx
│   │   └── register
│   │       └── page.tsx
│   ├── dashboard
│   │   ├── layout.tsx
│   │   └── page.tsx
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── fonts
│   │   ├── GeistMonoVF.woff
│   │   └── GeistVF.woff
│   ├── globals.css
│   ├── (home)
│   │   ├── layout.tsx
│   │   └── page.tsx
│   └── layout.tsx
├── components
│   ├── auth
│   │   ├── LoginForm.tsx
│   │   └── RegisterForm.tsx
│   ├── layout
│   │   ├── header.tsx
│   │   ├── SidebarItem.tsx
│   │   └── Sidebar.tsx
│   ├── registry
│   │   ├── RegistryAccountForm.tsx
│   │   └── RegistryAccountList.tsx
│   └── types.tsx
└── lib
    ├── dbOperations.ts
    ├── db.ts
    └── schema.sql

the src/app/api/auth/register/route.ts code:
import {NextResponse} from "next/server";
import {createUser} from "@/lib/dbOperations";

export async function POST(request: Request) {
  try {
    const {username, email, password} = await request.json();
    const user = await createUser(username, email, password);
    return NextResponse.json({user}, {status: 201});
  } catch (error) {
    return NextResponse.json({error: "Registration failed"}, {status: 400});
  }
}

I need help with figuring out it is returning a 404 and fixing it.
To add more context:
This is my login route file:
import {NextResponse} from "next/server";
import {verifyUser} from "@/lib/dbOperations"; // Assuming the path is correct
import {sign} from "jsonwebtoken";

const JWT_SECRET = process.env.JWT_SECRET || "your-secret-key";

export async function GET() {
  return NextResponse.json({success: "Login Found"}, {status: 200});
}

export async function POST(request: Request) {
  try {
    const {username, password} = await request.json();
    const user = await verifyUser(username, password);

    if (user) {
      const token = sign({userId: user.id}, JWT_SECRET, {expiresIn: "1h"});
      return NextResponse.json({token, user});
    } else {
      return NextResponse.json({error: "Invalid credentials"}, {status: 401});
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return NextResponse.json({error: "Login failed"}, {status: 400});
  }
}

When I comment out the POST handler, or comment out the content of the try block, the route no longer returns a 404. I can hit the GET route. But once I restore the commented content, it returns a 404.
The component making the request:
'use client'

import { useState } from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'

export default function LoginForm() {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
  const router = useRouter()

  const handleSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    try {
      const response = await fetch('/api/auth/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({ username, password }),
      })
      if (response.ok) {
        const { token } = await response.json()
        localStorage.setItem('token', token)
        router.push('/dashboard')
      } else {
        const data = await response.json()
        alert(data.error)
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Login error:', error)
      alert('Login failed')
    }
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="space-y-4">
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="username" className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
          Username
        </label>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="username"
          value={username}
          onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
          required
          className="mt-1 block w-full rounded-md border-gray-300 shadow-sm focus:border-indigo-300 focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-200 focus:ring-opacity-50"
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="password" className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
          Password
        </label>
        <input
          type="password"
          id="password"
          value={password}
          onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          required
          className="mt-1 block w-full rounded-md border-gray-300 shadow-sm focus:border-indigo-300 focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-200 focus:ring-opacity-50"
        />
      </div>
      <button
        type="submit"
        className="w-full flex justify-center py-2 px-4 border border-transparent rounded-md shadow-sm text-sm font-medium text-white bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500"
      >
        Login
      </button>
    </form>
  )
}

I have tested everything and found that the issue comes from the verifyUser function
import db from "./db";
import {hash, compare} from "bcrypt";

export interface User {
  id: number;
  username: string;
  email: string;
}

export interface RegistryAccount {
  id: number;
  user_id: number;
  registry_name: string;
  access_token: string;
}

export interface DeletionSchedule {
  id: number;
  registry_account_id: number;
  image_name: string;
  tag_pattern: string;
  cron_expression: string;
}

export interface GCSchedule {
  id: number;
  registry_account_id: number;
  cron_expression: string;
}

export const createUser = async (
  username: string,
  email: string,
  password: string
): Promise<User> => {
  const passwordHash = await hash(password, 10);
  const stmt = db.prepare(
    "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password_hash) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
  );
  const result = stmt.run(username, email, passwordHash);
  return {id: result.lastInsertRowid as number, username, email};
};

export const getUserByUsername = (username: string): User | undefined => {
  const stmt = db.prepare(
    "SELECT id, username, email FROM users WHERE username = ?"
  );
  return stmt.get(username) as User | undefined;
};

export const verifyUser = async (
  username: string,
  password: string
): Promise<User | null> => {
  const stmt = db.prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?");
  const user = stmt.get(username) as
    | (User & {password_hash: string})
    | undefined;
  if (user && (await compare(password, user.password_hash))) {
    const {password_hash, ...userWithoutPassword} = user;
    return userWithoutPassword;
  }
  return null;
};

export const createRegistryAccount = (
  userId: number,
  registryName: string,
  accessToken: string
): RegistryAccount => {
  const stmt = db.prepare(
    "INSERT INTO registry_accounts (user_id, registry_name, access_token) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
  );
  const result = stmt.run(userId, registryName, accessToken);
  return {
    id: result.lastInsertRowid as number,
    user_id: userId,
    registry_name: registryName,
    access_token: accessToken,
  };
};

export const getRegistryAccounts = (userId: number): RegistryAccount[] => {
  const stmt = db.prepare("SELECT * FROM registry_accounts WHERE user_id = ?");
  return stmt.all(userId) as RegistryAccount[];
};

export const createDeletionSchedule = (
  registryAccountId: number,
  imageName: string,
  tagPattern: string,
  cronExpression: string
): DeletionSchedule => {
  const stmt = db.prepare(
    "INSERT INTO deletion_schedules (registry_account_id, image_name, tag_pattern, cron_expression) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"
  );
  const result = stmt.run(
    registryAccountId,
    imageName,
    tagPattern,
    cronExpression
  );
  return {
    id: result.lastInsertRowid as number,
    registry_account_id: registryAccountId,
    image_name: imageName,
    tag_pattern: tagPattern,
    cron_expression: cronExpression,
  };
};

export const getDeletionSchedules = (
  registryAccountId: number
): DeletionSchedule[] => {
  const stmt = db.prepare(
    "SELECT * FROM deletion_schedules WHERE registry_account_id = ?"
  );
  return stmt.all(registryAccountId) as DeletionSchedule[];
};

export const createGCSchedule = (
  registryAccountId: number,
  cronExpression: string
): GCSchedule => {
  const stmt = db.prepare(
    "INSERT INTO gc_schedules (registry_account_id, cron_expression) VALUES (?, ?)"
  );
  const result = stmt.run(registryAccountId, cronExpression);
  return {
    id: result.lastInsertRowid as number,
    registry_account_id: registryAccountId,
    cron_expression: cronExpression,
  };
};

export const getGCSchedules = (registryAccountId: number): GCSchedule[] => {
  const stmt = db.prepare(
    "SELECT * FROM gc_schedules WHERE registry_account_id = ?"
  );
  return stmt.all(registryAccountId) as GCSchedule[];
};


Could you please [edit] your question to include the client-side code that makes the requests?

FYI these are Route Handlers, not API Routes

@phil, yes i know. But the client code isn't so much of the issue. When I test the routes with curl, or .http, I get the same results. It works when I comment out a section of the POST handler. In fact, I have narrowed it down to the first two lines.

The most probably cause of a 404 is an incorrect URL so instead of assuming that your client-side code is correct, please include it in your question so others can see for themselves. Even an example curl request would help
